# Which swing tool is used?

Tags: java, swing

I have a java program installed on my computer that creates Forms and can later print it. I want to do something similar with my program! In the source folders of this program, I found folders for the specific forms. Each folder containes a `image` for e.g named `Payment.png` and a `xml` file is structured like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="windows-1250" standalone="no"?>
<form xmlns:xinclude="http://www.w3.org/2001/XInclude" blankodruck="true" filename="Payment.png" saveAndPrintButtonEnabled="true" scale="1.0" title="Payment" window_height="725" window_width="860" paper="A5" orientation="landscape">
  <printscale sx="0.432" sy="0.434"/>
  <printoffset x="0" y="13"/>
   <model class="de.hans.client.app.form.payment.PaymentModel" />
  <printform filename="Payment.png" pngscaleX="1" pngscaleY="1"/>

  <offset x="-20" y="15" scaleX="0.72" scaleY="0.7" printOffsetX="4" printOffsetY="3" printScaleX="2.34" printScaleY="2.33">
        <xinclude:include href="../Header.xml"/>
    </offset>

<checkbox height="33" name="Paydaten_ChB" width="35" x="862" y="74" printOffsetX="0" printOffsetY="0"/>
 <checkbox columns="90" height="35" ...

<textfield columns="1" height="36" name="quartal" width="35" x="1235" y="72" printOffsetX="0" printOffsetY="0"/>
<radiobutton group="Gender" height="36" name="User_gender" tooltip="men" width="33" x="1253" y="130" printOffsetX="0" printOffsetY="0"/>
```

It has even a barcode-field:

```
<barcode length="886" type="3" px="430" py="180" pages="1">
  <invisible name="date"/>
  <invisible name="titel"/>
```

Can somebody guess how this printable swings are created in the program? Thanks

Comment: What's a *printable swing*?

Comment: @VinceEmigh It's one you can print on 3D printer ;)

Comment: I saw special attributes in the xml-file like: `printOffsetX="4" printOffsetY="3" printScaleX="2.34" printScaleY="2.33"`

Comment: And i want to print it on a real paper form so the data has to be positioned right!

Comment: It looks to me to be their own internal format.  What program are you using?

Comment: I found something in the source folders a class file that was named jgoodies?